# Problems with flutter console and C:users\Dell

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm following a person's beginner's flutter tutorial but their flutter opens with 0:\developments\ while mine opens with C : Users\Dell. How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Why exactly is it an *issue*? I guess your user name is "Dell". Assuming the rest of the world has picked other names, you will never come across a tutorial with the same path, even if it's on the same operating system storing their user's home directory in the same path ("C:\Users\").

Comment: @nvoigt How can I switch it from C:\users\ to :0\developments\?

Comment: You cannot. That's like asking "I saw a gardening tutorial, but the guy lived on Main Street, how can I change my address to Main Street?". You don't. You make the tutorial work in your own home. If you have actual *problems* with this, like something isn't working or you get error messages, *then* ask a question about that here.

Comment: @nvoigt thank you, I am quite new to this stuff